# Trouble with loading a csv from a migration script in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, load-data-infile

When trying to load a csv from a migration script using something like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
    "load data local infile 'my_data.csv' into table my_table fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' (column1, column2)
```

I get:

```
Mysql2::Error: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version: load data local infile....
```

I have already added the appropriate settings to my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=1
[mysql]
local-infile=1
```

If I run my "load data local infile" command from a mysql client (e.g., mysql -uname -p) it works great.  For some reason in a migration script (from rails) it fails with the "not allowed with this MySQL version".

Comment: Your sql command above it not complete (copy/paste)? Did you try just  "LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES STARTING BY 'xxx'" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)?

Comment: Thanks, but I know the statement works in mysql command line.  I was able to get past this without the migration.

Comment: But we don't (know that).

Comment: Sorry - I still don't have the answer since I just used a script (shell) to run this via mysql to get by for now.  I still need the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using [activerecord-fast-import](https://github.com/jsuchal/activerecord-fast-import) (which is based on the same type of import query), and found out that, for [security reasons](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data-local.html), **both the server and the client** need to have this enabled.

The setting on (`my.cnf`) is indeed needed for the server. To enable it on the client, just add this to `database.yml`:

`local_infile: true`